# Hide div when mobile pinch zoom level > 100%

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, zooming, pinchzoom, hammer.js

I would like to hide a div when the mobile zoom level (as initiated by a pinch zoom gesture on a mobile browser) is larger than 100%.

E.g. when a user slightly zooms in on a webpage, the div disappears (because this div is fixed and I don't want it to be visible when zoomed in, otherwise it's enlarged self takes over the entire viewport.

I am currently using jQuery and jQuery mobile and can use hammer.js if that helps?

Cheers from New Zealand!
Phill

---

This is what I've tried so far

```
Hammer(document).on("pinch", function (event) {
    if (event.gesture.scale > 1) {
        $('#test').text(event.gesture.scale);
        $('.sb-slide').fadeOut();
    }
    else {
        $('.sb-slide').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please include the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: @WimOmbelets Ok, I have edited my post to include the code that I have tried so far.

Comment: I'm also keen to know how to detect this, you can't do     var hammertime = new Hammer(document).on('pinch etc..